# Synchronous use of FRID reader

Tags: winforms

I will briefly explain the situation.
I'm developing an application, a log of training exercises using a FRID reader, the concept is that when a person scans a card, a countdown timer is triggered, after the end of the class, data about the beginning and end of the class is sent to the database, if the person is tired of working out and does not fit in on time, then when the card is scanned again, the lesson stops, and the database displays that the lesson was stopped. there is a problem that when you launch two “simulators” a bug appears, that is, if one person starts a “simulator” and is working out at a given moment in time, then when you start the second, etc. “simulator”, the lesson at the first “simulator” may stop . I need help on how to make sure that FRID readers are assigned to one text box and do not conflict with another reader when working synchronously.
P.S.
readers are displayed on the computer as keyboards, I didn’t find any drivers
Development is carried out in Visual Studio 2022, Windows Forms C#

chatGPT produced this code, but I don’t know how to declare readers
To implement input splitting between two keyboards in a Windows Forms application, you will need to complete the following steps:

1. Define two forms (Form1 and Form2) in your application that will accept input.
2. On each form, add a control to display text, such as a TextBox.
3. In the program class, create two keyboard instances (Keyboard1 and Keyboard2).

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TwoKeyboardsExample
{
static class Program
{
static void Main()
{
// Create keyboards
Keyboard1 keyboard1 = new Keyboard1();
Keyboard2 keyboard2 = new Keyboard2();

```
         Application.Run(new Form1(keyboard1));
         Application.Run(new Form2(keyboard2));
     }
 }

 // Class for the first keyboard
 public class Keyboard1
 {
     public event EventHandler<string> KeyPressed;

     public void OnKeyPressed(string key)
     {
         KeyPressed?.Invoke(this, key); // Call an event
     }
 }

 // Class for the second keyboard
 public class Keyboard2
 {
     public event EventHandler<string> KeyPressed;

     public void OnKeyPressed(string key)
     {
         KeyPressed?.Invoke(this, key); // Call an event
     }
 }

 // Form for the first keyboard
 public class Form1 : Form
 {
     private readonly Keyboard1 keyboard1;

     public Form1(Keyboard1 keyboard1)
     {
         this.keyboard1 = keyboard1;
         keyboard1.KeyPressed += Keyboard1_KeyPressed; // Subscribe to keyboard event 1

         TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
         Controls.Add(textBox1);
     }

     private void Keyboard1_KeyPressed(object sender, string key)
     {
         // Handling the keyboard key press event 1
     }
 }

 // Form for the second keyboard
 public class Form2 : Form
 {
     private readonly Keyboard2 keyboard2;

     public Form2(Keyboard2 keyboard2)
     {
         this.keyboard2 = keyboard2;
         keyboard2.KeyPressed += Keyboard2_KeyPressed; // Subscribe to keyboard event 2

         TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox();
         Controls.Add(textBox2);
     }

     private void Keyboard2_KeyPressed(object sender, string key)
     {
         // Handling the keyboard key press event 2
     }
 }
```

}

4. In the Form1 class, subscribe to the KeyPressed event of the Keyboard1 instance to handle the keypress event.
5. In the Form2 class, subscribe to the KeyPressed event of the Keyboard2 instance to handle the keypress event.

Now each keyboard will be bound to its own form and will work independently of each other.